# JQuery .remove() removes more elements than was selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have two different tables next to each other. I do some stuff with them and everything goes right, but when I want to remove one of them (first child of their parent), it removes both. I tried lot of ways to select first element, like: `:first-child, :first, .first(), :nth-child(1), eq(0)`... but none of them work if I use `.remove()`. On other hand when i use for example `.empty()`, it works. So here is my question: What is causing this problem?

```
<div class="calendar_wrapper_border ">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                something here
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                something here
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
<script>
    //doesn't work
    $('.calendar_wrapper_border table:first-child').remove();
    //does work
    $('.calendar_wrapper_border table:first-child').empty();
</script>
```

As i said it doesn't work with any 'first' selector. One more thing is, that both tables are generated with JQuery and appended to that DIV. But for me it makes no sense, that .empty() works but .remove() removes both tables.
If someone can give me explanation of my mistake that I probably made i will be thanksful.

I will give you the whole structure of this html code.

```
<div class="calendar_wrapper_border">
 <table class="calendar">
  <tbody>
    <tr class="names"> 
      <td class="day             name_of_day">Po</td> 
      <td class="day name_of_day">Út</td> 
      <td class="day name_of_day">St</td> 
      <td class="day name_of_day">Čt</td> 
      <td class="day name_of_day">Pá</td> 
      <td class="day name_of_day">So</td> 
      <td class="day name_of_day">Ne</td>
    </tr>
    <tr> 
      <td class="day disabled" date="30-3-2015">30</td> 
      <td class="day disabled" date="31-3-2015">31</td> 
      <td class="day" date="1-4-2015">1</td> 
      <td class="day" date="2-4-2015">2</td> 
      <td class="day" date="3-4-2015">3</td> 
      <td class="day" date="4-4-2015">4</td> 
      <td class="day" date="5-4-2015">5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr> 
      <td class="day" date="6-4-2015">6</td> 
      <td class="day" date="7-4-2015">7</td> 
      <td class="day" date="8-4-2015">8</td> 
      <td class="day" date="9-4-2015">9</td> 
      <td class="day" date="10-4-2015">10</td> 
      <td class="day" date="11-4-2015">11</td> 
      <td class="day" date="12-4-2015">12</td>
    </tr>
    <tr> 
      <td class="day" date="13-4-2015">13</td>
      <td class="day" date="14-4-2015">14</td> 
      <td class="day" date="15-4-2015">15</td> 
      <td class="day" date="16-4-2015">16</td> 
      <td class="day" date="17-4-2015">17</td> 
      <td class="day" date="18-4-2015">18</td> 
      <td class="day" date="19-4-2015">19</td>
    </tr>
    <tr> 
      <td class="day" date="20-4-2015">20</td> 
      <td class="day" date="21-4-2015">21</td> 
      <td class="day" date="22-4-2015">22</td> 
      <td class="day" date="23-4-2015">23</td> 
      <td class="day" date="24-4-2015">24</td> 
      <td class="day" date="25-4-2015">25</td> 
      <td class="day" date="26-4-2015">26</td>
    </tr>
    <tr> 
      <td class="day selected" date="27-4-2015">27</td> 
      <td class="day" date="28-4-2015">28</td> 
      <td class="day" date="29-4-2015">29</td> 
      <td class="day" date="30-4-2015">30</td> 
      <td class="day disabled" date="1-1-2015">1</td> 
      <td class="day disabled" date="2-1-2015">2</td> 
      <td class="day disabled" date="3-1-2015">3</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  </table>
  <table class="calendar">
  <tbody>
    <tr class="names"> 
      <td class="day             name_of_day">Po</td> 
      <td class="day name_of_day">Út</td>
      <td class="day name_of_day">St</td> 
      <td class="day name_of_day">Čt</td> 
      <td class="day name_of_day">Pá</td> 
      <td class="day name_of_day">So</td> 
      <td class="day name_of_day">Ne</td>
    </tr>
    <tr> 
      <td class="day disabled" date="30-3-2015">30</td> 
      <td class="day disabled" date="31-3-2015">31</td> 
      <td class="day" date="1-4-2015">1</td> 
      <td class="day" date="2-4-2015">2</td> 
      <td class="day" date="3-4-2015">3</td> 
      <td class="day" date="4-4-2015">4</td> 
      <td class="day" date="5-4-2015">5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr> 
      <td class="day" date="6-4-2015">6</td> 
      <td class="day" date="7-4-2015">7</td> 
      <td class="day" date="8-4-2015">8</td> 
      <td class="day" date="9-4-2015">9</td> 
      <td class="day" date="10-4-2015">10</td> 
      <td class="day" date="11-4-2015">11</td> 
      <td class="day" date="12-4-2015">12</td>
    </tr>
    <tr> 
      <td class="day" date="13-4-2015">13</td> 
      <td class="day" date="14-4-2015">14</td> 
      <td class="day" date="15-4-2015">15</td> 
      <td class="day" date="16-4-2015">16</td> 
      <td class="day" date="17-4-2015">17</td>
      <td class="day" date="18-4-2015">18</td> 
      <td class="day" date="19-4-2015">19</td>
    </tr>
    <tr> 
      <td class="day" date="20-4-2015">20</td> 
      <td class="day" date="21-4-2015">21</td> 
      <td class="day" date="22-4-2015">22</td> 
      <td class="day" date="23-4-2015">23</td> 
      <td class="day" date="24-4-2015">24</td> 
      <td class="day" date="25-4-2015">25</td> 
      <td class="day" date="26-4-2015">26</td>
    </tr>
    <tr> 
      <td class="day selected" date="27-4-2015">27</td> 
      <td class="day" date="28-4-2015">28</td> 
      <td class="day" date="29-4-2015">29</td> 
      <td class="day" date="30-4-2015">30</td> 
      <td class="day disabled" date="1-1-2015">1</td> 
      <td class="day disabled" date="2-1-2015">2</td> 
      <td class="day disabled" date="3-1-2015">3</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
 </table>
 </div>
```

And I want to delete one of those tables, but unsuccessfully.

Comment: In your selector, you're saying inside the calendar wrapper, for EACH table, remove the first child

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/n1514sn7/1/ Possible solution accessing the first <td> of the first <table>.

Comment: Your code [works as expected in this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7p4enokg/).

Comment: Your first example works fine http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/ufpe9q3a/

Comment: This is assuming you want to remove the first table, and not the tables first-child, right?

Comment: The truth is that both his examples are actually working, therefore both "something here" are being removed (or made empty). If it is not working, then I suspect that he probably didn't either include jquery or forgot the <script> tag or to include the js file including the script.

Comment: or they're not waiting for the elements to be created before trying to alter them.

Comment: I tried almost everything you said to me, but every solution seems to be wrong. It do not remove whole table.

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem in a jsFiddle?

Comment: To answer the question **What is causing this problem?**, we can't. The problem is not within the code you've provided. If you can provide a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) reproducing the issue, we can better assist you.

Comment: @DavidMinařík If you found an answer to the problem by going through the steps we suggested (e.g. reproducing the issue), than it's no waste of time at all. **And welcome to StackOverflow :)**

Comment: Thanks @Ted , well waste of your time, but still you helped me. And welcome to StackOverflow only in term of asking. That's how i was able to always solve my problem. Just thanks to this site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, when I was trying to reproduce the problem, I find out where was this problem. And I deserves as much downvotes as possible for this. Problem was, that I was calling this function in callback of .animate() function. But this function ran 2 times, cause it was animating both tables (for sure!) and thats why it always removed both. First animation-> removed first table; Second animation->removed first table(in this situation the only one remaining). And that's how I find out that I'm idiot :) sorry for wasting your time guys.

Comment: @StefanWittwer I would like to, but it doesn't let me accept it as answer for 2 days (Just because it's my own answer)